# htaccess - Allow access for my dhcp ip address only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create a temporary .htaccess file on my test server so that only my public dhcp ip can access my test sites.

I have three lines in my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond expr "file('%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myip') != %{REMOTE_ADDR}"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blackhole2.html [R,L]
```

The first line reads the output of my php script file written in /myip file. If the address does not match 'remote_addr' then forward to an appropiate webpage. ie: blackhole2.html

It looks like if the ip addresses match I can gain access to my test site.
However, if the ip address does not match, the rewrite rule errors with 302 looping errors.

I have tried several flag delimiters etc. but have now thrown my toys out of my I.T. drawer.

What have I overlooked, or not understood what else is required.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This triggers a redirect-loop when the IP address does not match because the redirected response to `/blackhole2.html` is caught by the same rule and redirected to `/blackhole2.html` again and again....

You need to include an exception for when `/blackhole2.html` is requested.

For example:

```
:
RewriteRule !^blackhole2\.html$ /blackhole2.html [R,L]
```

Or simply block the request (403 Forbidden) and don't redirect:

```
:
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Although you will need to create an exception if you have a custom 403 `ErrorDocument`.

Comment: All good on both versions...just altered your typo. Thanks.